# Dynamically switching receive locations between database servers

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Using BizTalk I need to read data from one of two databases that are hosted in Unix using ODBC.

The data is replicated between the databases and if one of the databases does not respond I need to switch to the other. There is no load balancer or anything so I need to be able to do the switch on the BizTalk server.

I was thinking of creating two receive locations, one for each database server, only one of them enabled and then have a Windows service that periodically tries to make a connection to one of the database servers and if there is an exception, call a powershell script that disables the receive location for the server that does not respond and enable the other receivelocation.

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: What timescales are we talking about here - i.e. how quickly do you need to know whether DB1 is down and DB2 is the new primary? What polling frequency do you have? How do you know DB1 is down - is it a connection thing, or will ping suffice?

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this as follows:

- In Biztalk create a single http receive location.
- Create a windows service
- In the windows service poll the first database, if it does not respond poll from the second database
- Have the Biztalk service post the information to the http receive location

You need to consider what happens if you read the same data twice, once from the main database and once from the backup.

Comment: I would like to have as little dependencies between the service and the database schema as possible so that I won't have to update the service if anything changes in the database schema.